# Unable to create pod

Tags: ios, swift2, cocoapods, podspec

I am trying to create a pod of library. I am following this [tutorial](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/creating-your-first-cocoapod--cms-24332). Pod lint successfully validate the pod spec. However when i import it as module i get error `Use of unknown type`. [Here is the project](https://github.com/mzeeshanid/MZDownloadManager)

**Update:**

- I just created a new pod project using the command `pod lib create
  MZDownloadManager`.
- Then I updated the meta in podspecs file like description, summary etc.
- Then I validated the podspecs using the command `pod lib lint MZDownloadManager` and it gives success.
- Then I goto the Example project directory and run the command `pod install`.
- It also successfully integrated the development pod.
- Then I goto the pregenerated class `ReplaceMe` and created the test class named `ReplaceMe` and just define its testing initialiser.
- Then I import the module. I still got the same error of `Use of undeclared type`

[image]

podspec file looks like this:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Let me know whether you get error in Importing or running podfile?

Comment: I am getting error when i try to use the source files.

Comment: Have you checked your podfile libs?is it there or not?

Comment: Yes i can see them in the pod project

Comment: is your thirdparty is on swift or Objective c?Doing any bridging header?

Comment: It is written in swift

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I figured out the issue after spending so many hours. The problem was that my classes in my development pod is not declared as public and [docs](https://guides.cocoapods.org/making/using-pod-lib-create.html) clearly states that:

> It's worth mentioning here, as this catches people quite often, a
>   Swift library needs to have it's classes declared as public for you to
>   see them in your example library.

I hope this will save time of other developers facing similar issue.

Answer (score -1):

Please make sure that your target membership is selected.

To see the target membership. Select your file then open the file inspector (⌥ + ⌘ + 1) [option] + [command] + 1

Also remove extra build phases.check bundle resources.Please do check whether you have assigned same variable name or same method name with MZDownloadManager.If so replace with some other name and run.

Do clean,build and then Run..

Comment: then the problem must be on bundle resources.check it out.If you have any copy on build phases Do remove it and clean,build and Run

Comment: I think something is wrong with public source files.

Comment: I think you have assigned same method name or some variable name with the name of MZDownloadManager.Change if any and run the project,Because you have you pod file perfect.so i am sure the issue is on source file.